# If I use a colorless commander, can I use colored spells?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

In Commander, your General's color identity defines what other cards you get to use, but what happens when you have a colorless General? Can you play any other colors of cards (WUBRG), or are you stuck playing only colorless?

Answer (score 13):

You can only use cards with a colorless color identity with a commander that has a colorless color identity.

[Rule 903](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Commander_(format)) has the rules for the commander format, and the following subrules are relevant here:

> - **903.4.** The Commander variant uses color identity to determine what cards can be in a deck with a certain commander. **The color identity of a card is the color or colors of any mana symbols in that card’s mana cost or rules text, plus any colors defined by its characteristic-defining abilities (see rule 604.3) or color indicator (see rule 204).**
> - **903.5.** Each Commander deck is subject to the following deck construction rules.
>
>   - **903.5c** A card can be included in a Commander deck only if every color in its color identity is also found in the color identity of the deck’s commander.

"Colorless" color identity means that the card has **no colors** in its color identity. If you tried to put a card in your deck that had any colors in its cost or rules text or indicator, then it would have a color in its color identity that is not in the commander's color identity.

Comment: I don't know if this is worth noting, but you couldn't use cards with Devoid in a deck with a commander that has no colors in its color identity, unless those cards had no color identity themselves.

Comment: I think it should be pretty clear, from the explicit mention of "colors of any mana symbols in that card's mana cost". Plus, there are multiple exceptions: cards with Deviod can't be used for one reason, Transguild Courier can't be used for another, and Elbrus, the Binding Blade isn't allowed for yet another reason.